# Stop Python from Converting Blob from SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, blob

I am trying to move pdfs as a blob from sql server to hbase.  When I use pypyodbc to retrieve the blob it is converting its format.  In SQL server it looks like

> 0x255044462D312E

but when I pull it into the unix server with pypyodbc it being converted to

> %PDF-1.5
>   %▒▒▒▒

is there a way to prevent this from happening and have the binary retain its original form?

pypy call is:

```
sql_conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER="+server+";UID="+user+";PWD="+passwrd+";DATABASE=DB") 
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Id,IMG_DESCRIPTION,binary FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB] WHERE Id IN "+join_list)
return cursor.fetchall()
```

Update:

It looks like in the SQL server it decoded in Latin-1 but when I try and move it, its being encoded by python.  It looks like ascii is the python default. I need to prevent this from happening or encode it back.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this issue and figured I'd share.

They way python 2.7 is built it is trying to be helpful by converting any binary string it sees to ascii.  To prevent this from happening you can convert your field to a string in SQL itself to prevent the conversion.  You can also cut off the '0x' at the start to makes sure its not being recognized as a binary string.

My fixed call

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Id,IMG_DESCRIPTION,convert(varchar(max),binary,2) FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB] WHERE Id IN "+join_list)
```